# Set JS property to object or null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an `nodejs` application that serves data about systems, each system have a number of contact persons which are of the type employee.

Whenever someone requests a system I have a script that populates the employees which is related to the system.

The code I have now looks like this:

```
if(row.system_owner){ 
  row.system_owner=emps[(row.system_owner).toUpperCase()];
}
if(typeof(row.system_owner) !== 'object'){
  row.system_owner = null;
}
```

Where row is an instance of system, and emps is an object containing all employees. The reason for this is that initially a system only contains a reference to an employee, but here the reference is swapped for the entire employee object.

The code works great, but I was wondering if it is possible to make it a one liner, more like this, and skip the second `IF statement`?

```
if(row.system_owner){ 
  row.system_owner=emps[(row.system_owner).toUpperCase()] ? Object 
  : null
}
```

Comment: `row.system_owner=row.system_owner && emps[(row.system_owner).toUpperCase()]`

will give you `value` or undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `&&` and `||` operators

```js
b = {
  key: 'value'
}

a = undefined
res = a && b[a]
console.log(res) // undefined


a = 'key'
res = a && b[a]
console.log(res) // 'value'


//if you need null, you can use || operator

a = undefined
res = a && b[a] || null
console.log(res) // null
```

In your case

```
row.system_owner=row.system_owner && emps[(row.system_owner).toUpperCase()]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try using turnary operator in a following way:

```
if(row.system_owner){ 
  row.system_owner = typeof(row.system_owner) === 'object'
      ? emps[(row.system_owner).toUpperCase()]
      : null;
}
```

I can imageine that this is what you wanted to achieve with your proposal.